# Increase virtual memory in Java

Tags: java, memory

I have a java application which loads a 1GB music file to play but gives an OutofMemory error since the available RAM is not much. It works perfectly fine on smaller files of size less than 600 mb(that too when I have the minimum and maximum available memory set to 512mb and 1536mb resp.). I am using a 2GB RAM machine

I need to know whether I can use my hard disk memory in place of RAM(due to storage limitation). If yes, can you please refer the articles for reference.

I am using this code to stream music:

```
DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format, size);
audioStream.read(audio, 0, size);

audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
audioClip.addLineListener(this);
audioClip.open(format, audio, 0, size);
```

Please comment if I'm missing something.

Comment: Why not stream the music file from disk instead of loading the whole thing into RAM?

Comment: I have added the code being used. Please inform if I'm missing something

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac ?

Answer (score 2):

It is better to just stream the music instead

http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-play-back-audio-in-java-with-examples

Create an AudioInputStream from a given sound file: 
    File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);

```
AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
```

Acquire audio format and create a DataLine.Infoobject:

```
AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
```

Obtain the Clip:

```
Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
```

Open the AudioInputStream and start playing:

```
audioClip.open(audioStream);

audioClip.start();
```

Close and release resources acquired:

```
audioClip.close();

audioStream.close();
```

Comment: I think I am using the same approach. I have even tried closing the stream at the end but it doesn't help since the file is not even getting played

Comment: its hard to help you when you aren't definite about what your problem is

Comment: It seems that Clip was the cause of this problem. Playing back using a SourceDataLine solved the issue as mentioned in http://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-play-back-audio-in-java-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, it's called virtual memory or a pagefile.

Since you're on windows you'll want to go to:

Control Panel -- System and Security -- System -- Advanced system settings -- Performance -- Advanced Tab

And then you should see an option for changing the amount of virtual memory available.

---

This has major drawbacks, as RAM is specially designed memory and it's quite fast, so you won't get the same performance out of your hard drive memory. The better option, in a resource sense, is to stream the audio and then manipulate it that way, if that's an option.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference. I think that there is a leakage in my code somewhere else. Although, I have a question. When I load a 1 GB file to play in my application. Does it run on RAM or Virtual Memory?

Comment: @lakshay It probably runs on your RAM since you're not seeing a change in performance. Are you using an IDE? If that's the case then you can google how to allow using more memory when running the program from that IDE. for instance in Eclipse you can go to run configurations and then change the VM arguments. you can put `-Xmx2048M` into the VM args to allow more heap space.

Comment: Tried that. The file gets played but not properly.1 second of the file gets played in around 5 real seconds.